# Appending BEGIN EXCEPTION lines into plsql file using sed

Tags: plsql, sed, oracle10g

I have a few sql files which contain thousands of INSERT statements. The problem when executing these scripts is that some of them violate the unique constraint.

I originally did something like this:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO .....;
    INSERT INTO .....;
    ...
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
       null;
END;
/
EXIT;
```

However it seems the first instance where the exception occurs will cause the entire block to end, so the rest of the statements are not executed.

Since the Oracle version I'm using is not 11, I can't use the nice CONTINUE command. So I am thinking of doing something like this for **each** INSERT INTO statement:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ....;
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
       null;
END;
/

...
```

How can I use sed to read each line in the sql file, scan for the words "INSERT INTO" and if that exists, then append the BEGIN and EXCEPTION lines in between the INSERT INTO line? The reason is, sometimes a line is just a comment and I don't want to append to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if you are trying to add `BEGIN` before a block of `INSERT INTO` lines, or if you simply want to add `BEGIN`/`EXCEPTION` lines around each `INSERT INTO` line.  If the latter:

```
sed '/^ *INSERT INTO/{ i\
BEGIN
a\
EXCEPTION
}' input-file
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I wanted a BEGIN / EXCEPTION around each INSERT INTO line. This works!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem in more than one way. One sloution is to detect that record is not duplicate before inserting. This can be done like this

```
select cout(*) INTO v_count

Fron table1 tb

where tb.column_name1 = val1;

IF v_count == 0 THEN
    insert into table1 values (val1, vale2....);
END IF;
```

Here you are inserting only when there is no duplication.

Another way can be create a procedure and call the procedure instead of insert.
Here is psedo code

```
create procedure insert_row (val1 varchar2, val2 varchar2)
IS
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO ....; 

EXCEPTION  
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN 
        null; 
END;
```

This procedure will handle exception due to duplicate record in calling procedure.

You can also write a loop. That depend on your data and logic of the program. Pdedo code is

```
Loop
    /* get the date from the cursor*/
    fetch cursor_c into record_r 

    EXIT WHEN  cursor%NOTFOUND;

    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO .....; 
        EXCEPTION  
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN 
                null; 
    END; 
END LOOP;
```

For getting all inserts use simple grep -i statement. This will collect all inserts in file. You can write a PL/SQL or C/C++/Java language program to generate new SQL script.